# Excel: set chart values using table headings

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a table called 'EvalPRJCum' in which I want to use a row to be added to a chart

```
Set ch = ws.ChartObjects("DiagrammEvalPrj")
With ch.Chart
    ch.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    lastEntry = .FullSeriesCollection.Count
    For index = 1 To lastEntry
        .FullSeriesCollection(index).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .FullSeriesCollection(index).AxisGroup = 1
    Next

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    lastEntry = lastEntry + 1
    .FullSeriesCollection(lastEntry).Name = "Kostensumme"
    .FullSeriesCollection(lastEntry).Values = "=EvalPRJCum[[#Ergebnisse];[11.2021]:[12.2022]]"
    
    .FullSeriesCollection(lastEntry).ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .FullSeriesCollection(lastEntry).AxisGroup = 2
End With
```

This Line fails with error 1004

```
    .FullSeriesCollection(lastEntry).Values = "=EvalPRJCum[[#Ergebnisse];[11.2021]:[12.2022]]"
```

If I enter the exact same string in the gui it is converted to "=EvalCost!$B$20:$O$20"

Is it possible to use the HEader Strings in VBA? Can I convert to to the Range String from a Range object?

Comment: Try `.FullSeriesCollection(lastEntry).Values = Evaluate("=EvalPRJCum[[#Ergebnisse];[11.2021]:[12.2022]]")` if it still does not work, try using the standard separator "," (comma) instead of ";" (semicolon)...

Answer (score 0):

Your code applies a simple string as value - it is not read as formula.

You have to apply an array of values or a range.

Try this:

```vb
Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("EvalPRJCum")  '>> adjust this to the correct sheet.
    
.FullSeriesCollection(lastEntry).Values = lo.ListColumns("11.2021").Total.Resize(, 2)
```

Like that you are referencing the listobjects Totals-row of the two list columns.